# Check whether data is present at an index in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray`, I want to insert data inside it, the problem is first I want to check if the index where I'm inserting the data exists or not. How to do that?
I try something like that but nothing is working:

```
if ([[eventArray objectAtIndex:j] count] == 0)
```

or

```
if (![eventArray objectAtIndex:j])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (j < [eventArray count])
{
     //Insert
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question;  ludo is looking for something akin to a sparse array.

Comment: I'm stupid sometimes -,.- anyway thanks for this fast answer~ ^^

Comment: no no it's working perfectly, I didn't even think of that easy one haha

Answer (score 3):

`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are not sparse arrays.  Thus, there is no concept of "exists at index", only "does the array have N elements or more".

For `NSMutableArray`, the grand sum total of mutable operations are:

```
- (void)addObject:(id)anObject;
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)removeLastObject;
- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject;
```

All other mutability methods can be expressed in terms of the above and -- more specifically to your question -- removing an object does not create a hole (nor can you create an array with N "holes" to be filled later).

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question :P

Answer (score 0):

I've given a brief implementation of a sparse array in this question: [Sparse Array answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430086/nsmutablearray-insert-object-at-index/6468731#6468731)