# NSMutableArray insert object at index

Tags: objective-c

I have an empty mutable array. Is it possible to insert object at index 2 for example, while there's nothing at index 0 and 1? I mean to increase capacity dynamically or something like that. .Regards.

Comment: Hmm why would you wanna do that? :)

Comment: I need it for my mini project in university. :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` is not a sparse array; it does not allow empty slots that can be filled in later.  `initWithCapacity:` just hints to the array that it will be filled to a certain amount;  it isn't generally necessary in practice and, unless you know exactly how many items you are going to shove in the array, don't bother calling it (just use `init`).

A mutable array will quite efficiently grow in size as objects are added.

If you need a data structure that supports "holes", then either use something else or put a placeholder object in the slots that are supposed to be empty.

I.e. if you wanted an array with 10 slots, you might do:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) [a addObject: [NSNull null]];
```

You can then check if the retrieved object `isEqual: [NSNull null]` to know if the slot is empty or not.   And you can use `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` to stick an object at a specific index.

Or you could use a different data structure;  a dictionary with the indices as the keys would work, for example.

Comment: You can add a couple of category methods to automatically append `NSNull` objects as needed and check whether an element is the null object and return nil instead. This is how I did it: http://cutecoder.org/programming/behold-holy-array/

Answer (score 12):

You can use a [NSPointerArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) for that.

> NSPointerArray is a mutable collection
>   modeled after NSArray but it can also
>   hold NULL values, which can be
>   inserted or extracted (and which
>   contribute to the object’s count).
>   Moreover, unlike traditional arrays,
>   you can set the count of the array
>   directly.

---

`NSPointerArray` is available in OS X v10.5 and later and iOS 6.0 and later. If you target a lower OS version you can, for example:

- Use a `NSMutableDictionary`, wrap you indices into `NSNumber`s and use these as keys.
- Use a `NSMutableArray` and fill the "holes" with `NSNull` objects.

Comment: Yup;  I should have mentioned this.  NSPointerArray is an awesomely useful class!  However, NSPointerArray isn't available on iOS IIRC.

Comment: NSPointerArray is available on iOS 6 and later.

Answer (score 3):

Write yourself a SparseArray class using an underlying NSMutableDictionary. Something like this (minimal code, barely tested, but it should give you the idea).

```
@interface SparseArray : NSObject {

@private
  NSMutableDictionary* _dict;
  int count;
}

-(SparseArray*)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)anInt;
-(id)objectAtIndex:(int)anIndex;
-(void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(int)anIndex;
- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(int)anIndex;
-(int)count;
```

---

```
@implementation SparseArray

-(SparseArray*)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)anInt {

  if ((self = [super init])) {
    _dict = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:anInt] retain];
    count = 0;

  }
  return self;
}

-(id)objectAtIndex:(int)anIndex {

  NSNumber* key = [NSNumber numberWithInt:anIndex];
  id object = [_dict objectForKey:key];
  return object;
}

-(void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(int)anIndex {

  NSNumber* key = [NSNumber numberWithInt:anIndex];
  [_dict setObject:anObject forKey:key];
  count++;

}

- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(int)anIndex {

  NSNumber* key = [NSNumber numberWithInt:anIndex];
  id object = [_dict objectForKey:key];
  if (object) {
    [_dict removeObjectForKey:key];
    count--;
  }
}

-(int)count {

  return count;
}

-(void)dealloc {

  [_dict release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this object does not support fast enumeration. Even if you did add it by adopting `NSFastEnumeration` the implementation would either be very inefficient or would not guarantee the enumeration would be ordered (as you'd expect from an array object).