# In Objective-C, if addObjectAtIndex is called to built the array, then will initWithCapacity need to be called?

Tags: objective-c

In a book, I see the code:

```
words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[masterWordList count]];
```

and let's say `[masterWordList count]` is 15.  And then the code built the array up by using a loop for 10 times:

```
[words addObject:[masterWordList objectAtIndex:randomNum]];
```

I wonder why `words` has to be `initWithCapacity`... and to 15 slots?  Can't it be 10 or 11 (if a nil is needed at the end... and also, won't `addObject` automatically grow the array size?  I tried using `init` instead of `initWithCapacity` and the code worked too.  So can the code in the book be simplified to just `init`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initWithCapacity:` simply gives the class initializer a "hint" as to the eventual size of the array. That way, it can allocate enough space in advance if you know you're going to need it. Using `initWithCapacity:` can theoretically provide for better performance because it may mean that the array doesn't have to reallocate memory (internally) as you add objects to it (I don't know if it actually does this in the current implementation, but it's possible). As you've guessed, it's only a hint and using `initWithCapacity:` is entirely optional. Just because you've given `initWithCapacity:` a certain size doesn't mean your array can't grow to hold more elements than that. Also, calling `init` instead will work just fine.

Comment: Exactly. I'd recommend you use `-init` unless profiling shows that inserting objects is taking a lot of time. (This is not purely theoretical--I have had to use `-initWithCapacity:` for speed reasons... once.)

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder why words has to be initWithCapacity... and to 15 slots?

In fact, `initWithCapacity:` is [generally not necessary at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430086/nsmutablearray-insert-object-at-index/6430257#6430257). It [may or may not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948062/nsmutablearray-initwithcapacity-nuances) reserve space in a useful way. My understanding is that it's something of a historic appendage.

> Can't it be 10 or 11 (if a `nil` is needed at the end...)

It could be 10. As was mentioned [on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165794/in-objective-c-why-doesnt-arraywithobjects-add-a-nil-to-the-end-of-list-automa), `nil` *isn't part of the array*. It's just a sentinel value for the creating method call itself -- it's not an object and doesn't become a member of the collection.

> also, won't `addObject:` automatically grow the array size?

Yes it will; you can create a mutable array without specifying any starting size and it will grow as needed.

> So can the code in the book be simplified just to `init`?

Yes.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I accepted Andrew's answer for mentioning that it is a mechanism to provide hint so that the size doesn't have to dynamically grow every single time for performance reason